# NoneType Error while trying to use Py for auto text file translation

Tags: python, google-translator-toolkit

Im trying to develop something that is able to accept a txt file and translate what ever is in it to the languages which I have given it. I made a small test with this as I dont use python but I get this error when trying to translate.

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'"

The Code:

```
import re
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator

file_translator = Translator()

tFile = open('demo.txt', 'r')

if tFile.mode == 'r':
    content = tFile.read()
    print(content)

result = file_translator.translate(content, dest='fr')

with open('output.txt', 'w') as outFile:
    outFile.write(result.text)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with version 3.0.0. You need to install latest version:

```
pip install googletrans==4.0.0-rc1
```

Or, if you use PyCharm, you can do it here:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been reported in the official repository. See [this issue](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/280):

> For anyone receives NoneType' object has no attribute 'group, if you
> are currently using **googletrans==3.0.0**, please switch to
> **googletrans==3.1.0a0** for the temporary fix.

This fix doesn't work for some. If it doesn't work for you try to install version `4.0.0rc1`

```
pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1
```